# interacting with peripherals

Tags: .net, device

I am using **.net**
How can I start to **learn** programming using any device connected to PC ? 
Can you suggest **keywords** to use to get tutorials and e-books about this because i have no idea how to start ?

edit : what bothers me much is when i see any proposal on elance talking about this i ignore it

Answer (score 0):

You can't start programming with any device (even connected to PC) unless that device has the software that is needed for programming (which most don't. Only a rarity that I've seen a device have programming software that is compatible with it.). You mostly test the programming with other devices like Android. You can test apps on multiple thing ranging from phones and tablets to virtual machines to PC. To code for any device, you have to code in the language that the device's OS supports.